Ironsource LevelPlay Unity DemoProject always Ads are not available for rewarded and Interstitial Android build
A fresh new project
I imported the LevelPlay package 8.2.0
gradle.properties added
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Otherwise it fails to build
MobilDependencyResolver resolved all libraries
Test the Sample LevelPlay demo project, only banners work
Rewarded and Interstitial always logs
IronSource.Agent.isRewardedVideoAvailable - False
I watched every tutorial online to no avail
I don't know what else to try! Thought maybe my region doesn't have any ads, tried a VPN .. Honestly I have no idea what to try!
